# The force vector is not in the direction of the lowest potential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics

> An object moving on a one-dimensional line is subject to a force. The
>   force is conservative and the associated potential energy function is
>   $$U(x) = x^4 - 2x^2$$
>   Find the force vector.

The force vector for this potential function should be $\vec{F} = 4x^3 - 4x$, but if you examine their graph,[image]
we can see that the force vector doesn't always point the lowest energy point, i.e equilibrium point.So, what is the problem ? I mean physically, the force vector must always be in the direction of the lowest energy.Note that the function that is in the shape of reverse M is the potential function.

Comment: Note that $F = -\frac{dU}{dx}$

Comment: @Troy who says that ? Can you prove it ?

Comment: It's how a conservative force is defined. Check out the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force) on 'Conservative forces'.

Comment: See whether this helps you:http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pegrav.html

Comment: @Leth Most undergraduate physics textbooks should have a proof.

Comment: @Troy I used the fact that $F = - \frac{dU}{dx}$ but still while the x is negative the force is still not in the lowest potential direction

Comment: @Leth Let's consider the case of $x<0$. The minimum potential occurs at $x=-1$. For $-1<x<0$, the force is negative, indicating that the force is pointing towards to the minimum point ($x=-1$), in the $-x$ direction. For $x<-1$, the force is positive, which is once again pointing towards $x=-1$ ($+x$ direction). Similar argument can be constructed for the $x>0$ case.

Comment: @Leth I'm referring to the minimum potential, so that is when $dU/dx=0$, not when $U=0$.

Comment: Yeah I got it at the last second :)